# Prepositions in a context , "of" vs "for"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Would you use "of" or " for" in the next sentences:

1- To arrange a soft transition of  the authority and not a sudden one.

2-To arrange a soft transition for the authority and not a sudden one.

I mean to allow the movement of power from some one to another.

Comment: They mean different things (as is often the case with changing prepositions). Please have a look at the [tag info](/tags/prepositions/info). It would be helpful to edit your question to describe the situation your sentence refers to.

Comment: You've added a definite article, which is not good. *Power* in your explanation doesn't have one; but both mentions of *authority* do. There is obviously a **lot** more to what you're writing than this fragment (neither 1 nor 2 are complete sentences). There isn't nearly enough context for your texts.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, context is important.

1: We are moving the authority to sign checks from A to B; to arrange a soft transition **of** the authority...

2: We are proposing a re-organisation of the Valley Authority; to arrange a soft transition **for** the Authority...

It's a 'transition of' what's being transitioned, and a 'transition for' the agents affected by the transition.

PS: English being English, there are bound to be some exceptions.